# Existing handler is "not found"

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

I've created a custom control, inherited from DateTimePicker to handle "continuous typing".

```
Public Class TimePicker
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker

    Private keyPressed As Boolean = False
    Private switchPart As Boolean = True

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Private Shadows Sub KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        switchPart = True
        If e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 AndAlso e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9 Then keyPressed = True
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then switchPart = False
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ValueChanged
        ' Setup variable to store last value chosen between changes
        Static lastValue As Date = Date.FromOADate(0)
        If (Value.Hour <> lastValue.Hour OrElse Value.Minute <> lastValue.Minute) AndAlso keyPressed AndAlso switchPart Then
            SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}")
            keyPressed = False
        End If
        lastValue = Value
    End Sub

End Class
```

And I was very happy for years.
But lately, it started to refuse to compile a form that uses the following code:

```
Private Sub dtpStartingTime_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtpStartingTime.ValueChanged
    dtpEndingTime.Value = New DateTime(Math.Max(dtpStartingTime.Value.Ticks, dtpEndingTime.Value.Ticks))
End Sub
```

The ValueChanged in the Handles part is underlined in red and the message is

Error   BC30590 Event 'ValueChanged' cannot be found.

But if I click F12 on the underlined event, it brings me to the function defined in my custom control. So it is definitely found.

What is happening? It is already 10 times that I'm cleaning the solution, removing the bin folder to be sure. It doesn't work anymore.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you.

P.S.: I'm using VS2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think this means:

```
Public Shadows Sub ValueChanged
```

You are specifically telling your class to hide the member with the same name in the base class. Hiding an event with a method is just plain bad.

That's not how you change behaviour on events. In well-written code, every event has a corresponding method that exists specifically to raise that event. For more information, [read here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html). You should be overriding the appropriate methods like so:

```vb
Public Class TimePicker
    Inherits DateTimePicker

    '...

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(e As KeyEventArgs)
        'Code here is executed before any event handlers.

        MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)

        'Code here is executed after any event handlers.
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnValueChanged(e As EventArgs)
        'Code here is executed before any event handlers.

        MyBase.OnValueChanged(e)

        'Code here is executed after any event handlers.
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.
I'll stop searching the reason why it was working since April 2016 ans stopped this morning :)